# How to mimic logical XOR in ZX Spectrum basic?

Tags: logical-operators, xor, basic, retro-computing, zxspectrum

Sometimes when coding in ZX Spectrum Basic I need to evaluate logical expressions that are formed by two operands and a logical xor like this:

```
IF (left operand) xor (right operand) THEN
```

Since ZX Basic does only know NOT, OR and AND I have to resort to some sort of fancy calculation which includes multiple uses of left/right operands. This is awkward since it consumes time and memory, both sparse if you're working on an 8-bit machine. I wonder if there's a neat trick to mimic the xor operator.

To test the outcome I provide a small code sample:

```
 5 DEF FN x(a,b)=(a ??? b) : REM the xor formula, change here
10 FOR a=-1 TO 1 : REM left operand
20 FOR b=-1 TO 1 : REM right operand
30 LET r=FN x(a,b) : REM compute xor
40 PRINT "a:";a;" b:";b;" => ";r
50 NEXT b
60 NEXT a
```

Can you help me find a performant solution? So far I tried `DEF FN x(a,b)=(a AND NOT b) OR (b AND NOT a)` but it's somewhat clumsy.

**Edit:**

If you want to test your idea I suggest the [BasinC v1.69](https://emulationrealm.net/downloads/file/3293-basinc) ZX emulator (Windows only).

As @Jeff pointed out most Basics, such as ZX one's, do consider zero values as *false* and non-zero ones as *true*.

**I have adapted the sample to test with a variety of non-zero values.**

Comment: Logically, NOT(A AND B) AND (A OR B) ?

Comment: @Worse_Username that would work, but it doesn't speed up the code I have so far. ^^

Comment: I like the `<>` answer below, but another purely logical possibility if ZX BASIC supports function-style IF-ELSE would be IF A THEN (NOT B) ELSE (B) - in C, you could write it `a?!b:b`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I like the `<>` answer too, but it doesn't solve all cases. In fact I had statements like `50 IF a THEN GOTO 100` `60 IF NOT b...` `100 IF b THEN ...` mimicking the ternary operator but all the gotos make this a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I'm still looking for neat solutions, feel free to answer. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Seems my one (and more so its update) perform best? :-)

Comment: Don't forget the existence of https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com for a lot of similar wonderful questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DEF FN x(a,b)=((NOT a) <> (NOT b))
```

Using `NOT` as coercion to a boolean value.

**EDIT** Previously had each side with `NOT NOT` which is unnecessary for establishing difference between the two, as one will still coerce!

**EDIT 2** Added parens to sort out precedence issue.

Comment: I just realised it only needs one `NOT` on each side. Edited accordingly.

Comment: With your update I now get a 0 with `a=-1` and `b=0`, because `NOT` has lower precedence. Did you even test any of your proposals?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I couldn't get the environment to install. Added parens, should sort.

Comment: There are still some parens that could be squeezed, but it looks acceptable now.

Comment: Sorry I've been afk for a while. The shortest version I could derive from your answer so far is: `DEF FN x(a,b)=(NOT a) <> NOT b`.

Answer (score 11):

The logical xor is semantically equivalent to not equal.

```
IF (left operand) <> (right operand) THEN
```

should work.

Edit: In the case of integer operands you can use

```
IF ((left operand) <> 0) <> ((right operand) <> 0) THEN
```

Comment: Good answer - very concise

Comment: That's a nice one. I should have added that on ZX e.g. -1 evals to true. So there's still an edge case where -1 xor 1 is to consider. But nonetheless the answer is spot on.

Comment: Most BASICs seem to consider zero to be false, and not-zero to be true. Given that, I'm not sure why you consider `-1 XOR 1` to be an "edge case".

Comment: Hmm, I see. So not so edgy after all, true.

Comment: @macmoonshine As much as I like that answer, it's just not sufficient to cover all cases. This is why I issued a bounty.

Comment: Which case is not covered?

Comment: In this Basic 0 is False, but anything else is True, such as -1 or 3.14, so your comparison wouldn't work.

Comment: I've adapted it for this need.

Answer (score 5):

Considering very interesting and fun this question and the answers in here, I would like to share the results of some performance tests (performed on an emulator):
[image]

elapsed times are in seconds , less is best. 
the `x1 test` is only to see if the expression meets the requirements and includes the print out of results, the `x256` repeat the same test 256times without printing any output; the `without FN` tests are the same but without factoring the expression in an FN statement.

I share also [the code and test suite on github: https://github.com/rondinif/XOR-in-ZX-Spectrum-basic](https://github.com/rondinif/XOR-in-ZX-Spectrum-basic) for the benefit of all retro computing fanatics (..like me) and share our opinions

Comment: I did my best but at present I have carried out a few checks and may inadvertently commit involuntary inaccuracies; you can possibly open issues on github or fork-it/pull-request if you see possible improvements.

Comment: Franco, if you have the infrastructure set up already could you try my answer out for performance?

Comment: @Ed. [(NOT a <> NOT b)](https://github.com/rondinif/XOR-in-ZX-Spectrum-basic/blob/master/src/main/basic/xor07b.bas) performs quite well, I updated answer and git repo.

Comment: I read that as, if we eliminate your number 5 (since it only works with 1 and 0, not all valid boolean values in BASIC), my two (numbers 3 and 7) are the fastest?

Comment: Further update of my answer - previous two should probably be zapped from comparison as apparently they are incorrect too!

Comment: The shortest version I could derive from Eds answer so far is: `DEF FN x(a,b)=(NOT a) <> NOT b`. Would be great to have it in the table. @FrancoRondini

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, value are integer:
I think mathematical operation could be fun : (A-B)*(A-B) should work
It should be less time consuming based on simple operation.

Or with ABS : ABS (A-B)

Comment: This won't work because A and B are not just 0 or 1. In Basic an operand is True if <> 0. For instance if A is 2 and B is -1, you still need A xor B evaluate to 0 (False).

Comment: It works with the sample provided :) It depends on your way to manage boolean. It's basically easy to have it on boolean form by using A AND A or A OR A.

Comment: Yes, the question is about that. Find a performant way to get to boolean form 0/1 and do the xor. Maybe with SGN, idk?